# MongoDb C# Transaction has been aborted when writing to database

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am doing a transaction in a MongoDb database and when inserting or deleting I get the following exception:

> Command insert failed: Transaction has been aborted

. However I am not aborting the transaction deliberately. I tried reducing the commands sent to the database to a minimum but the exception still happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out there was a time limit for transactions. I ran the following command in the mongo shell and the transaction could complete.

```
db.adminCommand( { setParameter: 1, transactionLifetimeLimitSeconds: 3000 } )
```